# Mesh is not updating when changed from gui in threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js

I made a line mesh with elliptical shape, representing the orbit wiht eccentricity e, and semi-major axis a. The mesh is a child of a group called orbitGroup that contains other objects.
Also, I added a gui to change this parameters. Every time gui changes it calls the next function:

```
 function ElementsUpdate(){

            scene.remove(orbitGroup);
            orbitGroup.remove(Orbit);
            Orbit = undefined;
            Orbit = new THREE.Line( GetGeometryOrbit(GetOrbitLine(a,e,100)), materialOrbit);
            orbitGroup.add(Orbit);
            scene.add(orbitGroup);     

        }
```

The mesh (Orbit) is being created successfully. However the it does not update. I'm aware that `setGeometry` method is not working anymore. Any solution? I am replacing the mesh because replacing only the geometry seems to be more complicated.
Thanks beforehand for the help.

The project is in this [link](https://www.astrasolaris.org/galery/orbital_elements.html)

Comment: What does `GetGeometryOrbit` return?

Comment: A couple other notes: There's no need to remove the group; just remove `Orbit`. Be sure to dispose the geometry (`Orbit.grometry.dispose();`), but after that you can just set it to the new value (no need to assign it to `undefined`) and re-add it to the group.

Comment: Hi. GetGeomertyOrbit returns a buffer geometry object like: new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints( points );

Comment: Next question: What does `GetOrbitLine` return? If it's an array of vertex positions, there may be an easy way forward here...

Comment: I used this code:  orbitGroup.remove(Orbit);
                Orbit.geometry.dispose();
                Orbit.geometry = GetGeometryOrbit(GetOrbitLine(a,e,100));
                orbitGroup.add(Orbit);    It does not generates mistakes, however nor update the geomerty.

Comment: @TheJim01 GetOrbitLine returns a THREE.EllipseCurve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to replace the vertex (`position`) buffer and call it a day.

```js
function ElementsUpdate(){
  let points = GetOrbitLine(a,e,100).getPoints(); // THREE.Curve.getPoints
  Orbit.geometry.setFromPoints( points ); // replaces the position buffer
}
```

1. [`Curve.getPoints`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/extras/core/Curve.getPoints) gives you an array of the points on your elipse.
2. [`BufferBgeometry.setFromPoints`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/670b1e9e85356d98efa4c702e93c85dd52f01e1e/src/core/BufferGeometry.js#L311) replaces the `position` buffer, derived from your array of points.
3. Because it replaces the buffer (and the `BufferAttribute`) You should not need to mark anything as needing re-sent to the GPU.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. I used this:
   `Orbit_Line = GetOrbitLine(a,e); //get new curve
                Orbit.geometry.setFromPoints( Orbit_Line.getPoints(100) ); // replaces the position buffer`